# Mesh only displays as wireframe?

Tags: modifiers

I'm using non destructive Boolean methods to cut into the mesh. When I duplicate the Boolean it only becomes into a wireframe. I tried deleting the modifier and also tried to convert into mesh from curve trying different options but cant get the solid mesh again.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, perhaps go in the Properties > Object > Viewport Display > Display As and choose Solid (or Textured)

Comment: That's one place it didn't cross my mind! thanks moonboots!

Comment: You probably have an addon which sets this to wireframe automatically when you perform a boolean.  Usually, that's helpful, because it lets you see the result!

Comment: If the case as mentioned by @Ben please re-edit question with that information.

Comment: Maybe something like "Mesh stuck in wireframe after booltools copy"

Comment: I'm only using Bool Tool Ad-on: CTRL +  minus on the number pad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it has to do with the *Bool Tool* which automatically switch the display of the boolean object you're using to *Wire*. Go in the *Properties panel > Object > Viewport Display > Display As* and choose *Solid* (or *Textured*)